# add a custom view to JHipster app

Tags: jhipster

Is there a Yeoman way of creating all the necessary templates required when adding a new view in a JHipster app?  I want a simple static page, or a page that doesn't require a new entity.  Let's say I want to add an "About" page, I believe I would need to do the following:

Add the "About" link to **src/main/webapp/app/layouts/navbar/navbar.html**:

```
<li ui-sref-active="active">
    <a ui-sref="about" ng-click="vm.collapseNavbar()">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-wrench"></span>
        <span class="hidden-sm" data-translate="global.menu.about">About</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

Create the following new files:

- src/main/**webapp/app/about/about.controller.js**
- src/main/**webapp/app/about/about.html**
- src/main/**webapp/app/about/about.state.js**
- src/main/**webapp/i18n/en/about.json**, and any other language...

... and add the following lines in **webapp/index.html**:

```
<script src="app/about/about.state.js"></script>
<script src="app/about/about.controller.js"></script>
```

... and any necessary content to src/main/**webapp/i18n/en/global.json**.

Am I forgetting something?

Does this need to be done manually?  Is there a Yeoman command for creating a new view that is independent of an entity?  I know that [this question has been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33452083/add-custom-view-to-jhipster-app), but I'm hoping that things have changed since then.

Comment: Still a manual task. You don't need to add js files to your index.html, it's done auttomatically by gulp

Answer (score 3):

The jhipster module [Nav Element](http://www.jhipster.tech/modules/marketplace/#/details/generator-jhipster-nav-element) do it automatically for us. In addition it creates an angular component too for the new item in the menu.

Answer (score 2):

Here is instruction how to add static page:
https://codefitter2.blogspot.com/2016/09/how-to-add-new-menu-and-static-page-in.html

Answer (score 1):

You may try creating an entity without any fields or relations and with "--skip-server" option.

`yo jhipster:entity about --skip-server`

Comment: use the Nav Element from Xavi Torrens comment